# How to use LVM_GETITEM (iSubItem?)

Tags: listview, winapi

I'm trying to use `LVM_GETITEM` to get info about an item in a ListView. The message needs 2 parameters to work: `iItem` and `iSubItem` among other things. It seems clear that `iItem` is the index of the desired item in the ListView, but I am unclear what to use for `iSubItem`.

I've been using 0 and it seems to work just fine for me. Still, I'm curious, what is `iSubItem` and what is it used for? The documentation is not very enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iSubItem` refers to columns when the listview is in "details" mode (`LVS_REPORT`). The first (primary) column is subitem 0, the second is 1 and so on.

Comment: Wow, quick response! So, if I'm *not* using LVS_REPORT, 0 is fine for *iSubItem*?

Comment: Yes just use 0 unless you are specifically addressing the second and subsequent columns in report mode.

Comment: Perfect answer.